# AWS Lambda scala app No public method named handle with appropriate method signature

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a scala application which I have deployed on AWS lambda.
Previously my `Main` class signature looked like:

`object Main extends App {...}`

With this I was able to provide a *handler* in the AWS Lambda definition which Lambda was happy with to run. An issue I was having was that the return of the lambda was always `null`.

To overcome this `null` issue when integrating with the API Gateway I've started using Lambda's java API.
I've made `Main` a `class` which extends `RequestHandler`

```scala
package example

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.{Context, RequestHandler}

class Main extends RequestHandler[String, String] with ArgParser with LazyLogging  {

  override def handleRequest(input: String, context: Context): String = {
    val (wins, losses) = /* ... */
    s"""{"wins":$wins,"losses":$losses}"""
  }
```

If I provide the *handler* `example.Main::handleRequest` I get the following error:

(My actual handler contains the full package name which worked before I introduced the `RequestHandler`, so I'm confident it's not a mistyping on the *handler*.)

```
{
  "errorMessage": "No public method named handleRequest with appropriate method signature found on class class example.Main"
}
```

I'm using the following dependency:

```
"com.amazonaws"              % "aws-lambda-java-core"              % "1.2.0"
```

The definition of my lambda is defined [in Terraform code here](https://gist.github.com/tjheslin1/ab352bc2dffe1ef9b3cf098412d9405f) and my `jar` is stored in `s3`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but is there a potential issue that your wins, losses definition is deferred resulting in handleRequest being flagged as defered? Whst happens if you provide values for the them?

Comment: Hi GMc. I've stripped out the code which calculates this values and just put `???` for the purpose of the question. I can see how it's a bit missleading however so will update the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through quite a bit of trial and error, [and a post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/cf4zh4/aws_lambda_scala_app_no_public_method_named/). I finally have a working format that allows me to execute my lambda in the lambda UI, providing plain JSON, as well as being able to trigger the lambda via the API Gateway, which was my main goal.

```scala
class Main extends RequestStreamHandler {

  override def handleRequest(request: InputStream, 
                                output: OutputStream, context: Context): Unit = {

    val input = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(request).mkString

    val (wins, losses) = /* ... */
    output.write(s"""{"wins":$wins,"losses":$losses}""".getBytes("UTF-8"))
  }
}
```

This provided me with a working lambda function. However I still ran into issues when invoking the API Gateway.

Manually creating an API Gateway API, specifying an integration with my Lambda function, worked straight away. This highlighted an issue with my Terraform deployment.

Before I was using *Use Lambda Proxy integration* which was causing issues. Unchecking this box in the UI or , if using Terraform, setting `type = "AWS"` in `aws_api_gateway_integration` fixed this issue.

The next problem was with the JSON being provided in the request.

In the *Integration Request* section in the gateway UI, under *Mapping Templates*, I selected:

**Request Body Passthrough**: *When no template matches the request Content-Type header*

In Terraform this can be set on `aws_api_gateway_integration` as:

`passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"`

With this I was able to use the `circe` JSON library to decode the the `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exact issue and been pondering the solution. Your page help me find the resolution. Thanks!

My code is more or less identical to yours

```
package com.magnets

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger

class Main extends RequestHandler[String, String] {

  override def handleRequest(input: String, context: Context): String = {
    val logger: LambdaLogger = context.getLogger
    logger.log("Input: " + input)
    "Hello World - " + input
  }
}
```

I defined the lambda function using an s3 location rather than uploading the uber jar, just like you did, I assume.

The "bug" is AWS won't update the jar file since it doesn't have a listener to the S3 location. You will need to either re-create the lambda fn (safest) or edit something within the function to trigger AWS to re-load from S3.

I simply Edit the Runtime settings after every upload to S3